# Wall-Sized Canvas Print

Tags: print-design, print-production, overprint

I am trying to figure out the **best medium** (at a good intersection of cost and quality) for an approximately **10 ft x 10 ft print**.

(This is for an exhibit that I'm putting on with my own budget. I'll likely mount this on some sort of large wooden wall)

I'm considering *printing to canvas*, or to a *softer more easily transportable-material* (rollable or foldable?).

Ideally, it would be one continuous piece of material... instead of taped together from smaller prints.

I am also considering custom wallpaper prints, such as large-format vinyl or "repositionable wallpaper" types - which run at between $500 and $800 for 10'x10'

If I'm printing through an online commercial printer, how can I pre-determine the quality and what it will look like on the material, before it's too late?

Any advice appreciated!

(This is related to - [Cheap very large scale printing methods (wall sized, 10,000 square feet)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/cheap-very-large-scale-printing-methods-wall-sized-10-000-square-feet) - but on a smaller surface area, and also I am open to commercial printing alternatives.)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the question you linked to, even if the final size is slightly different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cheap very large scale printing methods (wall sized, 10,000 square feet)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/cheap-very-large-scale-printing-methods-wall-sized-10-000-square-feet)

Comment: I've updated my question, where I explain that I am open to commercial printing solutions.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to define my problem very well. Would really appreciate constructive criticism before downvoting. This is a very un-welcoming stack community, to dis-able newbies from posting genuine questions!

Comment: So, my account is now banned from posting questions! I'm really sorry for posting this question. If there were a way to close this, I would, but I don't have that option either. How can I undo this damage? I'm sorry, again! :(

Comment: Wow, I don't know why this question got such a negative response. As the person who answered the "duplicate" I can say that it is NOT the same as this question...  that question is extreme, this one is routine. As well as canvas I'd recommend looking into exhibition **roller banners** (convenient but pricey), or **foam board**. For checking quality, talk to the print company, they should be very keen to show you samples and to discuss proofing.

Comment: While looking for an example print shop who does foam board I found  this guide to choosing materials for large-format print jobs, I think you'll find it very useful - http://www.supersizeprint.co.uk/materialsguide.aspx?mode=0 - be aware though that this example company's max size  for one sheet with no joins is 2.5 meters by 1.2 ( so about 8 feet by 4 feet )

Comment: hey, why did i just get downvoted for this? i thought it was protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing - Sizes that big already need a printer that prints things that are larger than usual, which will usually mean that you need some kind of industrial printer that by default will cost more money than regular prints.

The cheapest alternative I can think so will not necessarily be relevant for you but it is widely used for decorating walls and it's fairly cheap so here it goes:

You can design and cut stickers and create a custom made design from wall stickers that are cut in to create your design, usually what you actually design is a vector, but they can do picture too.  That way you don't need a specifically large printer just a lot of stickers, and most cutting places will send an expert to glue them to the wall perfectly according to the design, here are a few examples I found just googling "Wall sticker design":

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately, because there are way too many lines, using stickers, my design is going to be a lot of aligning hell.